# mod_rewrite: adding a 'fake folder' to all URLs?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

How would I, in apache 2.4.9, add a fake folder to all URLs?

Example:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

changes to

```
http://localhost/folder/index.html
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?folder(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: cannot I not put this in the virtual host conf file?

Comment: yes you can put edited rule in conf file (will require Apache restart)

Comment: What URL did you use to test it? When you enter `http://localhost/folder/index.html` does it not load `http://localhost/index.html`?